# No bouquets in this xui.one API http://localhost/accesscode/?api_key=****&action=create_line&is_trial=1&exp_date=2hour&bouquet=1&allowed_outputs?

Tags: xui

http://localhost/accesscode/?api_key=****&action=create_line&is_trial=1&exp_date=2hour&bouquet=1&allowed_outputs

How to get bouquets active when I run this line on browser?
Is creating empty list :((

I tried like that with same result:

http://localhost/accesscode/?api_key=****&action=create_line&is_trial=1&exp_date=2hour&bouquet=**bouquet name or bouquet id no.**&allowed_outputs...

Like following examples:

1. http://localhost/accesscode/?api_key=****&action=create_line&is_trial=1&exp_date=2hour&bouquet=**1**&allowed_outputs...
2. http://localhost/accesscode/?api_key=****&action=create_line&is_trial=1&exp_date=2hour&bouquet=**ViP**&allowed_outputs...